# SQL JOIN two table & show all rows for table A

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question about `JOIN`.

```
     TABLE A      |        TABLE B       |
-----------------------------------------|
    PK   |   div  |   PK   |  div  | val |
-----------------------------------------|
     A   |   a    |    1   |   a   |  10 |
     B   |   b    |    2   |   a   | 100 |
     C   |   c    |    3   |   c   |  9  |
------------------|    4   |   c   |  99 |
                  -----------------------
```

There are two tables something like above, and I have been trying to join two tables but I want to see all rows from `TABLE A`.

Something like

```
SELECT T1.PK, T1.div, T2.val 
    FROM A T1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN B T2 
        ON T1.div = T2.div
```

and I want the result would look like this below.

```
   PK   |  div  |  val  |
-------------------------
   A    |   a   |  10   |
   A    |   a   |  100  |
   B    |  null |  null |
   C    |   c   |   9   |
   C    |   c   |   99  |
```

I have tried all `JOIN`s I know but `B` doesn't appear because it doesn't exist. Is it possible to show all rows on `TABLE A` and just show `null` if it doesn't exists on `TABLE B`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes.  That is what your query should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your query to

```
SELECT T1.PK, T2.div, T2.val 
    FROM A T1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN B T2 
        ON T1.div = T2.div
```

(Note, that `div` comes from `T2` here.), you'll get exactly the result posted (but maybe in a different order, add an `ORDER BY` clause if you want a specific order).

Your query as it stands will get you:

```
   PK   |  div  |  val  |
-------------------------
   A    |   a   |  10   |
   A    |   a   |  100  |
   B    |   b   |  null |
   C    |   c   |  9    |
   C    |   c   |  99   |
```

(Note, that `div` is `b` for the row with the `PK` of `B`, not `null`.)

Comment: Thanks ! Although my problem wasn't actually because of this issue, I got a hint from this.

Answer (score 1):

To get to your resultset, all you need to do is use T2.Div as that is the value that does not exist in the second table:

```
SELECT T1.PK, T2.div, T2.val 
FROM A T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN B T2 
    ON T1.div = T2.div
```